# Conditional Formatting Relative vs Absolute

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two cells in a column. Both are the merger of two cells. D16 merged from D16 and D17, D18 merged from D18 and D19.  I have a conditional formatting rule as follows on them.

```
=SUM($D16:$D18)<>AA$21
```

When not equal both are red, but when equal D18 remains red.  I can't figure out why.  If I change it to this it works.

```
=SUM($D$16:$D$18)<>AA$21
```

I am trying to keep the rows relative because I need to copy and paste this a lot in my sheet.  Thanks for any help.

Here is a short example

[image]

A1:A3 CFR What I want to happen is when A1:A3 is not equal to B1 they both turn red, but what seems to be happening is A3 and A5 are adding up together.

```
=SUM($A1:$A4)<>B$1
```

A5:A7 CFR

```
=SUM($A5:$A8)<>C$1
```

Comment: *I need to copy and paste this a lot in my sheet* You mean the CF Rule? Can you not make an unique rule that applies to all target range?

Comment: Yes the CF.  Sorry not sure how to make what you are talking about.

Comment: CFR formulas are relative to each cell in the range that the CFR applies to. What cell are you trying to apply the first (relative row) formula to and where are you planning to copy it to? Your row is relative on one side of that equation and the column is relative on the other side.

Comment: This is the first one        =SUM($D16:$D18)<>AA$21        and the 2nd is.                  =SUM($D26:$D28)<>AB$21

Comment: Could you please post a data example? The input and how you would like the CF rule to work.

Comment: So the first is actually applied to the D16:D17 and D18:D19 merged cells?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: `=SUM($D16:$D18)<>AA$21` is how the D16:D17 merged cell is determined but `=SUM($D18:$D20)<>AA$21` is how the D18:D19 merged cell is determined and you want to fix that without making the rows absolute.

Comment: `=AND(SUM($D16,$D18)<>AA$21, SUM($D14,$D16)<>AA$21)` might work but it is going to depend on your overall layout and that's something you haven't shared.

Comment: *What I want to happen is when A1:A3 is not equal to B1 they both turn red* Thanks for your example, but in the image you have posted, merged cells are `A1:A2` , `A3:A4` and so on. I understand you want to fill red only those merged cells if they are not equal to B1. is that right? Or you need to sum up a pair of merged cells (in your exmaple, you would sum up `A1:A2` with `A3:A4` and if this sum is not equal to B1, then red color?